# Create and Insert documents using an async while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm trying to generate tokens on the fly and save them to the database as I do so.

This is the code to generate a token.

```
const generateToken = function (maxUse) {
  // 12 digit token numbers. 9e+11 possibilities
  const min = 100000000000;
  const max = 999999999999;
  const token =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max -min) + min);
  // ensure token doesn't exit exist in db before saving
  Token.count({ token }, function (err, count) {
    if (count > 0) {
      generateToken() ;
    } else {
      let newToken = new Token({ token, maxUse });
      newToken.save(function (err, savedToken) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        } else {
          generateSerial(savedToken._id);
          console.log("saved token is =>", savedToken.token);
          return savedToken.token;
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

How do I write a function that calls this function an arbitrary number of times, appending the the tokens to a file as they are being saved to the database. I realized a while loop wouldn't wouldn't work because of the asynchronous nature of the process.

All the answers I've seen assume that I have the bulk data ahead of time e.g using bulkwrite (mongoose).

An alternative approach is welcomed

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see this, you are probably best off keeping a "local list" of the generated tokens and "bulk" inserting via [`.insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany). Mileage may vary on the actual implementation, so we will discuss both that approach as well as handling your recursive function in a sane way with async methods.

### Async Loop

You have created a problem where you need to test the values present in order to determine that they are "unique" for insertion. This of course requires async calls in order to look at the database, and therefore rules out "bulk" actions such as "upserts" because you don't know if the item exists before you send it in a loop. So recursion does work in this case.

So the very first thing you should do is to make the "function" asynchronous itself, either returning a callback or a promise.

In essence:

```
function generateToken(maxUse) {
  const min = 100000000000;
  const max = 999999999999;
  const token =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max -min) + min);

  return Token.count({ token }).then( count => {

    if ( count > 0 ) {
      generateToken(maxUse);
    } else {
      return Token.create({ token, maxUse });
    }

  })
}
```

Or in more modern terms with async/await

```
async function generateToken(maxUse) {
  const min = 100000000000;
  const max = 999999999999;
  const token =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max -min) + min);

  let count = await Token.count({ token });

  if ( count > 0 ) {
    generateToken(maxUse);
  } else {
      return Token.create({ token, maxUse });
  }
}
```

Then it's really just a matter of calling in a loop, either in modern terms as:

```
let count = 0;
while (count < 500) {
  // Random usage 1-5
  const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  let token = await generateToken(maxUse);
  log(token.token);
  count++;
}
```

Or using [`async.whilst`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst) if running under a node version that does not support `async/await`:

```
 asyncWhilst(
    () => count < 500,
    (callback) => {
      const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 ) + 1;
      generateToken(maxUse).then(token => {
        log(token.token);
        count++;
        callback();
      }).catch(err => callback(err));
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      // Loop complete, issue callback or promise
    }
  );
```

So it's all relatively simple.

---

### Hold Unique Local and "Bulk Insert"

The "alternate" way to handle this is instead to keep an array of the generated tokens "on the client". Then all you need do on each random generation is see if the token was "already seen" and only create an insert operation when a "unique" value is obtained.

This should be much faster than going back and forth to the database with recursive calls since it's all "cached" locally.

In essence, make your generator function very basic:

```
function generateToken(maxUse) {
  const min = 100000000000;
  const max = 999999999999;
  const token =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max -min) + min);

  return ({ token, maxUse });
}
```

And then during the loop, make two arrays for the `seenTokens` and the `ops`, where the latter denotes the items to later insert in "bulk batches" instead of individual writes:

```
let count = 0,
    seenTokens = [],
    ops = [];

while ( count < 500 ) {
  const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

  let token = generateToken(maxUse);

  if ( seenTokens.indexOf(token.token) === -1 ) {
    seenTokens.push(token.token);
    ops.push(token);
    count++

    if ( count % 500 === 0 ) {
      await Token.insertMany(ops);
      ops = [];
    }
  } else {
    continue
  }

}

if ( count % 500 !== 0 ) {
  await Token.insertMany(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

Of course we are applying the `async/await` methods there, but that's only for the [`.insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) method being async, and if you are not actually inserting "tens of thousands" then it should be easily handled without even needing to "await" such a call, and then only issue **"once"**.

But the demonstration here accounts for what the code should look like when it "is tens of thousands" with no other alteration. Again you can use other library functions to "await" such calls as required.

And again we can employ [`async.series`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) and [`async.whilst`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst) for such control:

```
  let count = 0,
    seenTokens = [],
    ops = [];

  asyncSeries(
    [
      (callback) =>
        asyncWhilst(
          () => count < 500,
          (callback) => {
            const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

            let token = generateToken(maxUse);

            if ( seenTokens.indexOf(token.token) === -1 ) {
              seenTokens.push(token.token);
              ops.push(token);
              count++;

              if ( count % 500 === 0 ) {
                Token.insertMany(ops,(err,response) => {
                  console.log(count);
                  ops = [];
                  callback(err);
                });
              } else {
                callback();
              }
            } else {
              console.log("trying again: seen token %s", token.token);
              callback();
            }
          },
          callback
        ),

      (callback) => {
        if ( count % 500 !== 0 ) {
          Token.insertMany(ops,callback)
        } else {
          callback()
        }

      }
    ],
    (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      ops = [];
      // Operations complete, so callback to continue
    }
  );
```

All very much the same, and again the "flow control" is really only there to cater for "larger batches", and you could simply use the regular loop to build the `ops` entries and make one call only to [`.insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany), much as the `500` limit here actually does.

So the simplest form basically is:

```
let count = 0,
    seenTokens = [],
    ops = [];

// Regular loop
while ( count < 500 ) {
  const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

  let token = generateToken(maxUse);

  if ( seenTokens.indexOf(token.token) === -1 ) {
    seenTokens.push(token.token);
    ops.push(token);
    count++;
  }
}
// Insert all at once
Token.insertMany(ops,(err,result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  // now it's complete
})
```

Of course this whole alternate approach "hinges on" the fact that you never actually maintain "persistence" of the "tokens" in the database, and would not call this function again until those existing entries are cleared. We could "slurp" in all the "taken tokens" and exclude by the same "local cache". But over time this would grow significantly, so there is that point to consider in your overall choice.

---

As a full listing scaffolded for latest nodejs release, but the general usage is applied inside:

```
const asyncWhilst = require('async').whilst,
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const tokenSchema = new Schema({
  token: { type: Number, unique: true },
  maxUse: Number
});

const Token = mongoose.model('Token', tokenSchema);

// Logger helper

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}


// Function implementation
function generateToken(maxUse) {
  const min = 100000000000;
  const max = 999999999999;
  const token =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max -min) + min);

  return Token.count({ token }).then( count => {

    if ( count > 0 ) {
      generateToken(maxUse);
    } else {
      return Token.create({ token, maxUse });
    }

  })
}

// Main program
(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    console.log("using async/await");
    // clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(conn.models).map(m => conn.models[m].remove({}))
    );

    let count = 0;
    while (count < 500) {
      // Random usage 1-5
      const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
      let token = await generateToken(maxUse);
      log(token.token);
      count++;
    }

    let totalCount = await Token.count();
    console.log("Count is: %s", totalCount);

    // Or using async.whilst
    console.log("Using async.whilst");
    // clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(conn.models).map(m => conn.models[m].remove({}))
    );

    count = 0;
    await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      asyncWhilst(
        () => count < 500,
        (callback) => {
          const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 ) + 1;
          generateToken(maxUse).then(token => {
            log(token.token);
            count++;
            callback();
          }).catch(err => callback(err));
        },
        (err) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve();
        }
      );
    });

    totalCount = await Token.count();
    console.log("Count is: %s", totalCount);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

Or as an "alternate" process:

```
const asyncSeries = require('async').series,
      asyncWhilst = require('async').whilst,
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const tokenSchema = new Schema({
  token: { type: Number, unique: true },
  maxUse: Number
});

const Token = mongoose.model('Token', tokenSchema);

// Logger helper

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}


// Function implementation
function generateToken(maxUse) {
  const min = 100000000000;
  const max = 999999999999;
  const token =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max -min) + min);

  return ({ token, maxUse });
}

// Main program
(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    console.log("Using async/await");
    // clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(conn.models).map(m => conn.models[m].remove({}))
    );

    let count = 0,
        seenTokens = [],
        ops = [];

    while ( count < 500 ) {
      const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

      let token = generateToken(maxUse);

      if ( seenTokens.indexOf(token.token) === -1 ) {
        seenTokens.push(token.token);
        ops.push(token);
        count++

        if ( count % 500 === 0 ) {
          await Token.insertMany(ops);
          ops = [];
        }
      } else {
        continue
      }

    }

    if ( count % 500 !== 0 ) {
      await Token.insertMany(ops);
      ops = [];
    }

    totalCount = await Token.count();
    console.log("Count is: %s", totalCount);

    // using async.whilst and indeed async.series for control
    console.log("using asyc.whilst");
    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(conn.models).map(m => conn.models[m].remove({}))
    );

    await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      count = 0,
      seenTokens = [],
      ops = [];

      asyncSeries(
        [
          (callback) =>
            asyncWhilst(
              () => count < 500,
              (callback) => {
                const maxUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

                let token = generateToken(maxUse);

                if ( seenTokens.indexOf(token.token) === -1 ) {
                  seenTokens.push(token.token);
                  ops.push(token);
                  count++;

                  if ( count % 500 === 0 ) {
                    Token.insertMany(ops,(err,response) => {
                      console.log(count);
                      ops = [];
                      callback(err);
                    });
                  } else {
                    callback();
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log("trying again: seen token %s", token.token);
                  callback();
                }
              },
              callback
            ),

          (callback) => {
            if ( count % 500 !== 0 ) {
              Token.insertMany(ops,callback)
            } else {
              callback()
            }

          }
        ],
        (err) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          ops = [];
          resolve();
        }
      );

    });

    totalCount = await Token.count();
    console.log("Count is: %s", totalCount);


  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm gonna need a minute to assimilate all that you've written.I don't get the idea of cleaning the data associated with the models. Could you please explain. thank you

Comment: @segunchrist It's just a demo. So all I am doing is removing anything from the collection before creating "new" data. The result in each case is that 500 "unique" tokens are created. That's the point of a full listing. So you can run it yourself and see it working. Then "afterwards" you sit down and work out "why it works". But that also is explained in the answer itself. Main thing is "your function needs to be async itself", as well as the "loop" that handles it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Comment: @segunchrist That's okay. Added another example of how to to this by holding the "already generated" tokens "locally". So instead of needing async calls to "lookup" existing tokens, you could instead simply look at a "local array" and keep looping until one was unique. This would be a much more efficient approach than repeated and recursive async calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sample codes. Ensuring that each new token in the batch never existed in the database is of utmost importance as the current batch of tokens will be immediately printed to the user, so buffering in memory as an array would potentially cause some printed tokens to be missing in the database